# How to set property of a relation?

Tags: rdf, graph-databases, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I have the use case where I need to define a relationship between two nodes. but, again that relationship is having the attribute/property. The question is how can I define this property? what needs to be written inside the domain/range constraints? 
The two entities are:

```
:Equipment a owl:Class ;

:EquipmentType a owl:Class ;
```

The relation is:

```
:hasEquipmentType a owl:ObjectProperty;
```

Now, I have attribute 'FilterBy' which filters the EquipmentTypes based on different criteria mentioned in 'FilterBy'.

Comment: I don't get it. So far you have two classes and a property which relates instances of both classes. The obvious domain and range would be using each of the classes. So far so good. But what do you mean by "attribute"? RDF resp. OWL has only binary relations. Anything beyond has to be done via some kind of helper node/entity/individual or whatever. (modulo reification which usually is hard to query for later) Can you give a concrete example please? I mean, instances + the relation + the attribute

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I mean that I need to have filters so that the EquipmentType instances will be arranged with. In this example, I need to clarify that can we have the properties for relations in RDF. (just like Equipment can have the name, date, etc. can we have 'filterBy' property for my above relation)

Comment: in RDF you can use any resource in subject position of a triple, in OWL you'd have to use punning, i.e. using the same URI for different types of entity. In your case, you could add an individual with the same URI and add the facts. Or you use annotations.